# how to parse string of SQL contain ESCAPE in ANTLR4？

Tags: sql, parsing, antlr, grammar, antlr4

there are two ESCAPE type in SQL: \' AND ''
a input may like:

```
 SELECT '\'', '''';
```

I parse the string with this grammar:

```
STRING_LITERAL
 : '\'' ( '\\\'' | '\'\'' | ~'\'' )* '\''
 ;
```

but ANTLR parse the input error, the tree like this:
[error parsed tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCogA.png)

I also tried another type of STRING_LITERAL grammar with GREEDY: "?":

```
STRING_LITERAL
 : '\'' ( '\\\'' | '\'\'' | ~'\'' )*? '\''
;
```

but it also give me a error parse resule like this:
[error parsed tree in another grammar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTvcc.png)
the '''' should parsed as a string contain but not two empty string.

How should I modify the grammar to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't exclude the `\` in the `( ... )*`. Try this:

```
STRING_LITERAL
 : '\'' ( '\\\'' | '\'\'' | ~['\\] )* '\''
 ;
```

where `~['\\]` matches any char except `'` and `\`. You may want to include line break chars in it: `~[\r\n'\\]`.